# Exercise on the logic of propositions, and equivalences.

Tags: logic

The domain of the variable consists of the empty set. Determine if $$ \forall x (x ^ 2 + 1 = 9)$$ is true or false.

I believe that if it is true, because when speaking of for all $ x $ in emptiness, then any property is satisfied (by emptiness).

Comment: Correct. If the domain is the empty set, $\forall x P(x)$ is always true.

Comment: Thanks, for help me.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is correct, through the vacuous argument you claimed.

---

*(Mostly just making this community wiki so the question does have an answer and doesn't end up cluttering the unanswered queue down the road.)*

Comment: Thanks, for help me.